# SQL query the job at the step

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Server 2016. I have a job with 2 steps:

Step #1:

```
if exists (select * from T1 where number = 1)
    Run the Step2
else 
    Quit the job reporting success
```

Step #2 - it can do anything doesn't matter.

The problem:

Looking for a generic script (without hardcoded job and step names), which if Step1 met some condition, it would trigger Step2, otherwise quit.

As this command requires both to be provided:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job N'job_name' , 'step_name'
```

Comment: What do you mean *"query the current job step1 is in"*? A Step is *part* of a job, so you should know what job you added it to and it only belongs to one job; just like a table is an object within a database, it's not part of many databases.

Comment: Why not include Step 2 in the `else` clause?

Comment: Please elaborate more on what you are actually trying to achieve? That way we can assist better...

Comment: I want a generic script, which if Step1 met some condition, it would trigger Step2. And this should be generic script, so would be easy to apply on many jobs without providing the job or step name. The Step1 one should know in which job it is running so would start Step2 if con met.

Comment: So if Step 1 is met, maybe execute a stored procedure, else execute a different SP, otherwise break?

Comment: imagine there is a job having 5x steps. And run 2-4 steps only if condition in Step1 is met. 
So if Step1 con is met, carryon Step2, Step3, Step4, Step5.

Comment: Makes sense @Mund. Why not code it like this then `if exists (select * from T1 where number = 1) begin exec step 1; exec step 2; exec step 3, etc. end else break` Would that suffice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this by forcing the first job step to raise an error if the conditional statement is not met. A fairly simple way:

```
IF EXISTS <Your conditional statement>
  BEGIN
    SELECT 1
  END
ELSE
  BEGIN
    SELECT 1/0
  END
```

If your conditional exists, the `SELECT 1` will return a `Success` value for the step. If not, the `SELECT 1/0` will throw an error and the step will fail. Configure the first step so for `On Failure: Quit the job reporting success` and `On Success: Go to the next step`.

Comment: seems pretty simple solution, thank you, will use it!